# Deleting from Indexed Priority Queue (java)

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, priority-queue, indexed

I have an Indexed Minimum Priority Queue implemented as a heap. When deleting an indexed element, the code is:

```
 public void delete(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= maxN) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (!contains(i)) throw new NoSuchElementException("index is not in the priority queue");
    int index = qp[i];
    exch(index, n--);
    swim(index); // Why is this needed?
    sink(index);
    keys[i] = null;
    qp[i] = -1;
}
```

The rest of the code can be found here: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html

Since `pq[N`] is the last element in `pq[]`, and this is swapped with the element at `pq[i]` (which is to be deleted), wouldn't this mean that the value at `pq[i]` after the swap is larger or equal to `pq[i]` before the swap? The question is why do we have to call `swim(i)` at all and not just `sink(i)` alone? Under which specific conditions is there a need to call `swim(i)` after the swap?

(There are 3 arrays, `qp[]` and `keys[]` with corresponding indexes, and `pq[]` such that `qp[pq[i]]` = `pq[qp[i]]` = `i`.)

Comment: Is your queue implemented as a heap? The tag seems to suggest so, but please make it clear in the text. The correct answer depends on this piece of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since pq[N] is the last element in pq[], and this is swapped with the element at pq[i] (which is to be deleted), wouldn't this mean that the value at pq[i] after the swap is larger or equal to pq[i] before the swap?

No, that is not necessarily true.  The only requirement for a valid min-heap is that a child cannot be smaller than its parent.  While this means that the element in the first position is the smallest, it does **not** mean that the element in the last position is the largest.  Consider the following heap:

```
                1
      10                 2  
  15       18        5        3
16  17   19  20    7   8    6   4
```

`pq[N]` is `4` and yet there are lots of elements in that heap that are larger than it.  Suppose we wanted to remove `15` by replacing it with `4`.  `4` is smaller than `10` and so would have to be moved up the tree (using `swim`).